# pip install in python

Tags: python, pip

From what I understand when the -e flag is passed to pip , it looks for a setup.py file in the same directory. It then does python setup.py. I have installed https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia. In the installation, it tells me to do pip install -e ./slybot. It works.

Where is all the installation taking place. The reason is I need to change this file called portiacrawl located at https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia/tree/master/slybot/bin .However when I change it I know I have to run pip install -e again since this is where the install of portiacrawl is taking place. This seems too long. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When installed using pip files are stored inside **Lib/site-packages** located inside the python folder